# Multiprocessing Pool doesn't run Astropy Function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, astropy

I have a 500GB dataset and would like to analyze it with machine learning, requiring me to extract all the objects which have the parameter `"phot_variable_flag"` set to `"VARIABLE"`. The data set is split into ~1000 sub-files through which I have to parse and thus want to use multiprocessing to parse multiple files at the same time.

I have read up on Python's `multiprocessing` with `Pool` and have implemented it, however, am stuck with a certain Astropy command (`Table.read()`) not being executed.

I have tested the code for the following:

- The input data is correctly parsed and can be displayed and checked with `print`, showing that everything is loaded correctly
- A simple for-loop iterating through the entire input file and passing each filename to the `get_objects()` function works and produces the correct output

Thus a very basic non-parallel example works.

```
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp
from astropy.table import Table

def get_objects(file):
    print(file)
    data = Table.read(file)
    print("read data")
    rnd = data[data["phot_variable_flag"] == "VARIABLE"]
    del data
    rnd.write(filepath)
    del rnd

args = sys.argv[1:]

if __name__ == '__main__':

   files = args[0:]

   pool = mp.Pool(processes=12)

   [pool.apply_async(get_objects, args=(file,)) for file in files]
```

Running this code outputs 12 different file names as expected (meaning that the `Pool` with 12 workers is started?!). However, directly afterwards the code finishes. The `"read data"` `print` statement is not executed anymore, meaning that the call to `Table.read()` fails.

However, I do not get any error messages and my terminal resumes as if the program exited properly. This is all happening in a time frame that makes it impossible for the `Table.read()` function to have done anything, since a single file takes ~2-3 min to read in but after the filenames are being printed the program immediately stops.
This is where I am completely stuck, since the for loop works like a charm, just way too slow and the parallelisation doesn't.

Comment: You are creating your 12 processes, and then exiting the program immediately.  You need to call `.get()` or `.wait()` on the return values from `.apply_async()`.

Comment: Thank you, using the '.wait()' worked like a charm. However, I had another look in the documentation and couldn't find anything useful explaining it. Most examples on the wild web never use these function, or just the '.get()' when they need to actually retrieve results. Could you please explain why the '.wait()' is necessary and what is happening if I don't implement it?

Comment: Async-methods are non-blocking. Since you don't have anything else to do after `apply_async`, there's nothing preventing your main-process from exiting. `wait()`and `get()` are blocking calls, so they resolve the problem you created by needlessly using an `async`-method here in the first place. You should just use `pool.map()` in this case. Use an `async`-method when you need a non-blocking call because you have other stuff to do for your parent while the job is being processed.

Comment: When in doubt, try some simpler examples first to make sure you understand how something works.